# Regex that matches image links but exclude normal url?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to exclude all links from input string but allow image links.

https://www.example.com/X00132BhJk.jpg  => allowed

http://www.example.com/search?ident=X00132BhJk  => not allowed

so, suppose an input string like

```
<p>http://example.com/abc.jpg</p><img src='http://example.com/abc.jpg'/>http://example.com/222.jpg  http://example.com/xyz.aspx <a url='http://example.com/abc'/>
```

should only allow contents in P, img tags, other ones from text tag and A link should fail the test.

How can I achieve that result with Regex, I'm not good at Regex at all!

```
From http://regexr.com/     

/(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))/i   
  => looks like matches image link, still need a way to exclude normal link without .png, jpg, gif...
```

UPDATE:

I use jquery to parse html into html tags and make test on each html node content.

```js
 var str ="<p>http://example.com/abc.jpg</p><img src='http://example.com/abc.jpg'/> http://example.com/xyz.aspx?id=2 <a url='http://example.com/jpg/3'/><div id='abcd'>http://example.com/xyz.aspx?jpg=2 <br/> http: // example.com/xyz.aspx?jpg=2</div>http://example.com/xyz.aspx?jpg=20 ",
 html = $.parseHTML( str ),$log = $( "#log" );
 var regex = /^http[^ \!@\$\^&\(\)\+\=]+(\.png|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.jpg)$/;
 


$.each(html, function(i,el) {    
var src='';
switch(el.nodeName)
{
   case 'IMG':
   src = el.src;break;
   case '#text': src= el.textContent;break;
   default: src=el.innerHTML;
}
             console.log(el.nodeName  + ' - ' + src  + ' - ' +  regex.test(src));
            
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell if a URL references image content from the URL itself - you can only determine this from the mimetype and content returned from the URL. You need a better problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following regex:

```
^http.+(png|jpeg|gif|jpg)$
```

This would expect string to start with `http` and end with either one of the formats specified

```js
var regex = /^http[^ \!@\$\^&\(\)\+\=]+(\.png|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.jpg)$/;

var test = [
  "https://www.example.com/X00132BhJk.jpg", 
  "http://www.example.com/search?ident=X00132BhJk" , 
  "http:// example.com",
  "http:// sample.png",
  "http://test.com/png"
]

for (var i = 0; i< test.length; i++){
  console.log(regex.test(test[i]), test[i])
}
```

Comment: thanks, i think I'll a way to enhance that because sometimes, people try to trick the system just type blank  http:// example.com, not really an anchor link.

Comment: In that case, you can try `[^ @^&*\(\)\+]+` instead of `.+`

Comment: thanks for your help, I've updated the code. Good results.

Comment: Problem with this is, not all images end in an extension. Some can have get params after.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex pattern(for multiple urls):

```
\bhttps?:\/\/\S*?\/[^\/.]+\.(jpg|png)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/wUukjp/1/

Answer (score 0):

Two caveats:

1. This won't check the entire string to make sure it's a valid URL, there are plenty of other resources online about validating URLs
2. It's not possible to make sure that the link actually points to an image, that's only possible by actually sending a request to that URL and seeing what kind of resource is returned

Allowing for those two caveats you were pretty close. All you needed was to put a `^` at the start and a `$` at the end of the string to ensure that the `jpg` or `png` are the last characters in the string. I've also put an optional `e` in jpg, and you can add all the other image file extensions, like `gif`, `bmp`, etc:

```
^https?:\/\/.+\.(?:png|jpe?g)$
```